# How to use getElementByXpath and getElementsByXpath correctly?

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, casperjs

How can I get table 'td' values with CasperJS?

The HTML source looks like than this:

```html
<table id="my_table">
  <tr id='header'>
    <th>sth_head_name</th>
    <th>ath_head_name</th>
    <th>sth_head_name</th>
    <th>sth_head_name</th>
    <th>sth_head_name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>sth_value</td>
    <td>sth_value</td>
    <td>sth_value</td>
    <td>sth_value</td>
    <td>sth_value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>sth_value</td>
    <td>sth_value</td>
    <td>sth_value</td>
    <td>sth_value</td>
    <td>sth_value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>sth_value</td>
    <td>sth_value</td>
    <td>sth_value</td>
    <td>sth_value</td>
    <td>sth_value</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'd want to get table values using CasperJS. Firstly, I need to select the rows of table; and then I want to get 'td' values. How can I solve this?

I tried a lot of ways, but those didn't work. My solution would look like something similar that you can see below. Its important, that firstly select 'table_rows'; and then select that's td value inside the for cycle.

```js
var table_rows = casper.getElementsByXpath("//table[@id='my_table']/tr[not(@id='header')]");

for (var i = 0; i < table_rows.length; i++) {
  var firstRequiredCell_query = table_rows[j].getElementByXpath("//td[position()=2]");
  var secondRequiredCell_query = table_rows[j].getElementByXpath("//td[position()=4]");
  var firstRequiredCell = firstRequiredCell_query.text;
  var secondRequiredCell = secondRequiredCell_query.text;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CasperJS has two contexts. You can only access the DOM directly only from the page context which you get access to inside of [`casper.evaluate()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate)<sup>1</sup>. It is sandboxed and therefore variables defined outside are not available in `evaluate()`.

[`__utils__.getElementsByXpath()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/clientutils.html#getelementsbyxpath) and `__utils__.getElementByXpath()` are only available in the page context where `casper` is not available. Those two functions return DOM nodes directly, so those nodes itself don't have the `getElementByXpath()` function on them.

But you don't need that at all:

```
casper.then(function(){
    var info = this.evaluate(function(){
        var table_rows = __utils__.getElementsByXpath("//table[@id='my_table']/tr[not(@id='header')]");

        return table_rows.map(function(tr){
            return {
                a: tr.children[1].textContent,
                b: tr.children[3].textContent
            };
        });
    });
    this.echo(JSON.stringify(info, undefined, 4));
});
```

You can use all of the ways to traverse the DOM like `children`, `querySelector()` or `document.evaluate()`.

<sup>1</sup> Please also read the [PhantomJS documentation of the same function](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html).