# Using casperJS to scrape some links from a webpage

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm using casperJS 1.1.2 and phantomJS 2.1.1 to retrieve some links from a webpage.  The links I'm interested in all have the string "javascript" in the href attribute as shown below:

```
<td>
<a href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new 
WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$CenterContent$ctl01&quot;,
&quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false,
true))">Species A    
</a></td>
<td>
<a href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new
WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$CenterContent$ctl02&quot;,
&quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false,
true))">Species B   </a></td>
<td><a href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new
WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$CenterContent$ctl03&quot;,
&quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false,
true))">Sepcies C    </a></td>
<td>
<a href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new
WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$CenterContent$ctl04&quot;,
&quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false,
true))">Species D</a></td>
<td>
<a href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new
WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$CenterContent$ctl05&quot;,
&quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false,
true))">Species E    </a></td>
```

I wrote some script in casperJS to scrape all and write to file all the links where the href attributes contain a "javascript" string as shown below.

```
var links=[];
var casper = require('casper').create({
  waitTimeout: 10000,
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    pageSettings: {
        loadImages: false,
        loadPlugins: false
    }
});

var fs = require('fs');

casper.start("https://apps.ams.usda.gov/CMS/", function()
    {
       links = _utils_.getElementsByXPath('.//td/a[contains(@href,"javascript")]');
    });

fs.write("plantVarietyResults.json", links, 'w');


casper.run();
```

I can't figure out why my script doesn't write the links to the file properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some misconceptions about CasperJS and mistakes in your code:

- [It's `__utils__` and not `_utils_`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/clientutils.html).
- [`__utils__` is only available in the page context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34239226/1816580).
- [The page context can be accessed through `casper.evaluate`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate).
- Non-primitive objects like DOM nodes, [cannot be passed out of the page context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13444288/1816580). (and [reference](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html))
- If you are interested in the `href`, then you have to read the `href` property from a DOM element.
- `casper.start` is asynchronous, but `fs.write` isn't, so you have to put the `fs.write` call in another asynchronous function that is executed after `casper.start`.
- A JavaScript object doesn't simply convert itself to a JSON string. You have to do it yourself.

Here is an example that should work (untested):

```
casper.start("https://apps.ams.usda.gov/CMS/", function() {
    var links = this.evaluate(function(){
        return __utils__.getElementsByXPath('.//td/a[contains(@href,"javascript")]')
            .map(function(element){
                return element.href;
            });
    });
    fs.write("plantVarietyResults.json", JSON.stringify(links), 'w');
});

casper.run();
```

Here's a slightly shorter way:

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
casper.start("https://apps.ams.usda.gov/CMS/", function() {
    var links = this.getElementsAttribute(x('.//td/a[contains(@href,"javascript")]'), 'href');
    fs.write("plantVarietyResults.json", JSON.stringify(links), 'w');
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Artjom B.